# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, android-multidex, android-r8

I've have attempted to find ideas online regarding this error but I have failed.

Can anyone assist, please?

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\117.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\122.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\123.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\126.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\128.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\129.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\131.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\132.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\143.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\144.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\145.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\146.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\147.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\148.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\149.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\150.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\151.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\152.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\153.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\154.jar




Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\117.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\122.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\123.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\126.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\128.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\129.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\131.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\132.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\143.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\144.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\145.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\146.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\147.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\148.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\149.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\150.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\151.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\152.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\153.jar, D:\servant\app_oplus_qwy\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\154.jar

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException

   multiDexEnabled true

   implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["multidex"]
```

Comment: Did you try to `clean` and `build` your project ?

Comment: did you initialize multiDex in the Application class `attachBaseContext` `MultiDex.install(this);` [refer this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle)

Comment: public class BaseApplication extends MultiDexApplication

Comment: Please run `./gradlew --stacktrace ...` and provide the full stacktrace you get when the error happens.

Comment: I have dealt with the problem.Thanks ,everybody